# How can I solve this problem. (error: Cannot find getter for field.)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

I have a problem. I clone this github project. https://github.com/SimpleMobileTools/Simple-Calendar 
Then I update Kotlin in Android Studio. When I run project, I take errors and I didn't solve them.

That are errors when I build it:

```
22:51:20: Executing task 'build'...

Executing tasks: [build]

:app:checkDebugClasspath UP-TO-DATE
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin UP-TO-DATE
e: C:\Users\Ayberk\Simple-Calendar\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\simplemobiletools\calendar\pro\models\Event.java:11: error: Cannot find getter for field.
    private java.lang.Long id;
                           ^
e: C:\Users\Ayberk\Simple-Calendar\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\simplemobiletools\calendar\pro\models\Event.java:39: error: Cannot find getter for field.
    private java.lang.String importId;
                             ^
e: C:\Users\Ayberk\Simple-Calendar\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\simplemobiletools\calendar\pro\models\EventType.java:10: error: Cannot find getter for field.
    private java.lang.Long id;
                           ^
e: C:\Users\Ayberk\Simple-Calendar\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\simplemobiletools\calendar\pro\models\EventRepetition.java:10: error: Cannot find getter for field.
    private java.lang.Long id;
                           ^
e: C:\Users\Ayberk\Simple-Calendar\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\simplemobiletools\calendar\pro\models\EventRepetitionException.java:10: error: Cannot find getter for field.
    private java.lang.Long id;
                           ^
:app:kaptDebugKotlin
w: C:\Users\Ayberk\Simple-Calendar\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\simplemobiletools\calendar\pro\databases\EventsDatabase.java:7: warning: Schema export directory is not provided to the annotation processor so we cannot export the schema. You can either provide `room.schemaLocation` annotation processor argument OR set exportSchema to false.
public abstract class EventsDatabase extends androidx.room.RoomDatabase {
                ^
:app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUİLD FAILED in 4s
14 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 13 up-to-date
22:51:25: Task execution finished 'build'.
```

This is first errors' generated java class:

```
package com.simplemobiletools.calendar.pro.models;

import java.lang.System;

@androidx.room.Entity(tableName = "events", indices = {@androidx.room.Index(unique = true, value = {"id"})})
@kotlin.Metadata(mv = {1, 1, 13}, bv = {1, 0, 3}, k = 1, d1 = {"\u0000X\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0010\t\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0010\b\n\u0002\b\u0002\n\u0002\u0010\u000e\n\u0002\b(\n\u0002\u0010\u000b\n\u0002\b\u001c\n\u0002\u0010\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0002\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0019\n\u0002\u0010\u0000\n\u0002\b\u0003\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0003\n\u0002\u0010 \n\u0002\b\u0003\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0004\b\u0087\b\u0018\u0000 z2\u00020\u0001:\u0001zB\u00b9\u0001\u0012\b\u0010\u0002\u001a\u0004\u0018\u00010\u0003\u0012\b\b\u0002\u0010\u0004\u001a\u00020\u0005\u0012\b\b\u0002\u0010\u0006\u001a\u00020\u0005\u0012\b\b\u0002\u0010\u0007\u001a\u00020\b\u0012\b\b\u0002\u0010\t\u001a\u00020\b\u0012\b\b\u0002\u0010\n\u001a\u00020\b\u0012\b\b\u0002\u0010\u000b\u001a\u00020\u0005\u0012\b\b\u0002\u0010\f\u001a\u00020\u0005\u0012\b\b\u0002\u0010\r\u001a\u00020\u0005\u0012\b\b\u0002\u0010\u000e\u001a\u00020\u0005\u0012\b\b\u0002\u0010\u000f\u001a\u00020\u0005\u0012\b\b\u0002\u0010\u0010\u001a\u00020\u0005\u0012\b\b\u0002\u0010\u0011\u001a\u00020\b\u0012\b\b\u0002\u0010\u0012\u001a\u00020\u0005\u0012\b\b\u0002\u0010\u0013\u001a\u00020\u0003\u0012\b\b\u0002\u0010\u0014\u001a\u00020\u0003\u0012\b\b\u0002\u0010\u0015\u001a\u00020\u0003\u0012\b\b\u0002\u0010\u0016\u001a\u00020\b\u00a2\u0006\u0002\u0010\u0017J\u000e\u0010M\u001a\u00020N2\u0006\u0010O\u001a\u00020\u0000J\u0018\u0010P\u001a\u00020Q2\u0006\u0010R\u001a\u00020Q2\u0006\u0010O\u001a\u00020\u0000H\u0002J \u0010S\u001a\u00020Q2\u0006\u0010R\u001a\u00020Q2\u0006\u0010O\u001a\u00020\u00002\u0006\u0010T\u001a\u000201H\u0002J\u0010\u0010U\u001a\u0004\u0018\u00010\u0003H\u00c6\u0003\u00a2\u0006\u0002\u0010*J\t\u0010V\u001a\u00020\u0005H\u00c6\u0003J\t\u0010W\u001a\u00020\u0005H\u00c6\u0003J\t\u0010X\u001a\u00020\u0005H\u00c6\u0003J\t\u0010Y\u001a\u00020\bH\u00c6\u0003J\t\u0010Z\u001a\u00020\u0005H\u00c6\u0003J\t\u0010[\u001a\u00020\u0003H\u00c6\u0003J\t\u0010\\\u001a\u00020\u0003H\u00c6\u0003J\t\u0010]\u001a\u00020\u0003H\u00c6\u0003J\t\u0010^\u001a\u00020\bH\u00c6\u0003J\t\u0010_\u001a\u00020\u0005H\u00c6\u0003J\t\u0010`\u001a\u00020\u0005H\u00c6\u0003J\t\u0010a\u001a\u00020\bH\u00c6\u0003J\t\u0010b\u001a\u00020\bH\u00c6\u0003J\t\u0010c\u001a\u00020\bH\u00c6\u0003J\t\u0010d\u001a\u00020\u0005H\u00c6\u0003J\t\u0010e\u001a\u00020\u0005H\u00c6\u0003J\t\u0010f\u001a\u00020\u0005H\u00c6\u0003J\u00c4\u0001\u0010g\u001a\u00020\u00002\n\b\u0002\u0010\u0002\u001a\u0004\u0018\u00010\u00032\b\b\u0002\u0010\u0004\u001a\u00020\u00052\b\b\u0002\u0010\u0006\u001a\u00020\u00052\b\b\u0002\u0010\u0007\u001a\u00020\b2\b\b\u0002\u0010\t\u001a\u00020\b2\b\b\u0002\u0010\n\u001a\u00020\b2\b\b\u0002\u0010\u000b\u001a\u00020\u00052\b\b\u0002\u0010\f\u001a\u00020\u00052\b\b\u0002\u0010\r\u001a\u00020\u00052\b\b\u0002\u0010\u000e\u001a\u00020\u00052\b\b\u0002\u0010\u000f\u001a\u00020\u00052\b\b\u0002\u0010\u0010\u001a\u00020\u00052\b\b\u0002\u0010\u0011\u001a\u00020\b2\b\b\u0002\u0010\u0012\u001a\u00020\u00052\b\b\u0002\u0010\u0013\u001a\u00020\u00032\b\b\u0002\u0010\u0014\u001a\u00020\u00032\b\b\u0002\u0010\u0015\u001a\u00020\u00032\b\b\u0002\u0010\u0016\u001a\u00020\bH\u00c6\u0001\u00a2\u0006\u0002\u0010hJ\u0013\u0010i\u001a\u0002012\b\u0010j\u001a\u0004\u0018\u00010kH\u00d6\u0003J\u0006\u0010l\u001a\u00020\u0005J\u0006\u0010m\u001a\u00020\u0003J\u0006\u0010n\u001a\u00020oJ\u0006\u0010p\u001a\u00020\u0005J\u0006\u0010q\u001a\u000201J\f\u0010r\u001a\b\u0012\u0004\u0012\u00020\u00050sJ\t\u0010t\u001a\u00020\u0005H\u00d6\u0001J\u0014\u0010u\u001a\u0002012\f\u0010v\u001a\b\u0012\u0004\u0012\u00020\u00050wJ\t\u0010x\u001a\u00020\bH\u00d6\u0001J\u0006\u0010y\u001a\u00020NR\u001a\u0010\u0018\u001a\u00020\u0005X\u0086\u000e\u00a2\u0006\u000e\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\b\u0019\u0010\u001a\"\u0004\b\u001b\u0010\u001cR\u001e\u0010\n\u001a\u00020\b8\u0006@\u0006X\u0087\u000e\u00a2\u0006\u000e\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\b\u001d\u0010\u001e\"\u0004\b\u001f\u0010 R\u001e\u0010\u0006\u001a\u00020\u00058\u0006@\u0006X\u0087\u000e\u00a2\u0006\u000e\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\b!\u0010\u001a\"\u0004\b\"\u0010\u001cR\u001e\u0010\u0013\u001a\u00020\u00038\u0006@\u0006X\u0087\u000e\u00a2\u0006\u000e\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\b#\u0010$\"\u0004\b%\u0010&R\u001e\u0010\u0012\u001a\u00020\u00058\u0006@\u0006X\u0087\u000e\u00a2\u0006\u000e\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\b\'\u0010\u001a\"\u0004\b(\u0010\u001cR\"\u0010\u0002\u001a\u0004\u0018\u00010\u00038\u0006@\u0006X\u0087\u000e\u00a2\u0006\u0010\n\u0002\u0010-\u001a\u0004\b)\u0010*\"\u0004\b+\u0010,R\u001e\u0010\u0011\u001a\u00020\b8\u0006@\u0006X\u0087\u000e\u00a2\u0006\u000e\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\b.\u0010\u001e\"\u0004\b/\u0010 R$\u00100\u001a\u0002012\u0006\u00100\u001a\u0002018F@FX\u0086\u000e\u00a2\u0006\f\u001a\u0004\b0\u00102\"\u0004\b3\u00104R\u001e\u0010\u0015\u001a\u00020\u00038\u0006@\u0006X\u0087\u000e\u00a2\u0006\u000e\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\b5\u0010$\"\u0004\b6\u0010&R\u001e\u0010\t\u001a\u00020\b8\u0006@\u0006X\u0087\u000e\u00a2\u0006\u000e\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\b7\u0010\u001e\"\u0004\b8\u0010 R\u001e\u0010\u0014\u001a\u00020\u00038\u0006@\u0006X\u0087\u000e\u00a2\u0006\u000e\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\b9\u0010$\"\u0004\b:\u0010&R\u001e\u0010\u000b\u001a\u00020\u00058\u0006@\u0006X\u0087\u000e\u00a2\u0006\u000e\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\b;\u0010\u001a\"\u0004\b<\u0010\u001cR\u001e\u0010\f\u001a\u00020\u00058\u0006@\u0006X\u0087\u000e\u00a2\u0006\u000e\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\b=\u0010\u001a\"\u0004\b>\u0010\u001cR\u001e\u0010\r\u001a\u00020\u00058\u0006@\u0006X\u0087\u000e\u00a2\u0006\u000e\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\b?\u0010\u001a\"\u0004\b@\u0010\u001cR\u001e\u0010\u000e\u001a\u00020\u00058\u0006@\u0006X\u0087\u000e\u00a2\u0006\u000e\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\bA\u0010\u001a\"\u0004\bB\u0010\u001cR\u001e\u0010\u0010\u001a\u00020\u00058\u0006@\u0006X\u0087\u000e\u00a2\u0006\u000e\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\bC\u0010\u001a\"\u0004\bD\u0010\u001cR\u001e\u0010\u000f\u001a\u00020\u00058\u0006@\u0006X\u0087\u000e\u00a2\u0006\u000e\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\bE\u0010\u001a\"\u0004\bF\u0010\u001cR\u001e\u0010\u0016\u001a\u00020\b8\u0006@\u0006X\u0087\u000e\u00a2\u0006\u000e\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\bG\u0010\u001e\"\u0004\bH\u0010 R\u001e\u0010\u0004\u001a\u00020\u00058\u0006@\u0006X\u0087\u000e\u00a2\u0006\u000e\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\bI\u0010\u001a\"\u0004\bJ\u0010\u001cR\u001e\u0010\u0007\u001a\u00020\b8\u0006@\u0006X\u0087\u000e\u00a2\u0006\u000e\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\bK\u0010\u001e\"\u0004\bL\u0010 \u00a8\u0006{"}, d2 = {"Lcom/simplemobiletools/calendar/pro/models/Event;", "Ljava/io/Serializable;", "id", "", "startTS", "", "endTS", "title", "", "location", "description", "reminder1Minutes", "reminder2Minutes", "reminder3Minutes", "repeatInterval", "repeatRule", "repeatLimit", "importId", "flags", "eventType", "parentId", "lastUpdated", "source", "(Ljava/lang/Long;IILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;IIIIIILjava/lang/String;IJJJLjava/lang/String;)V", "color", "getColor", "()I", "setColor", "(I)V", "getDescription", "()Ljava/lang/String;", "setDescription", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", "getEndTS", "setEndTS", "getEventType", "()J", "setEventType", "(J)V", "getFlags", "setFlags", "getId", "()Ljava/lang/Long;", "setId", "(Ljava/lang/Long;)V", "Ljava/lang/Long;", "getImportId", "setImportId", "isPastEvent", "", "()Z", "setPastEvent", "(Z)V", "getLastUpdated", "setLastUpdated", "getLocation", "setLocation", "getParentId", "setParentId", "getReminder1Minutes", "setReminder1Minutes", "getReminder2Minutes", "setReminder2Minutes", "getReminder3Minutes", "setReminder3Minutes", "getRepeatInterval", "setRepeatInterval", "getRepeatLimit", "setRepeatLimit", "getRepeatRule", "setRepeatRule", "getSource", "setSource", "getStartTS", "setStartTS", "getTitle", "setTitle", "addIntervalTime", "", "original", "addMonthsWithSameDay", "Lorg/joda/time/DateTime;", "currStart", "addXthDayInterval", "forceLastWeekday", "component1", "component10", "component11", "component12", "component13", "component14", "component15", "component16", "component17", "component18", "component2", "component3", "component4", "component5", "component6", "component7", "component8", "component9", "copy", "(Ljava/lang/Long;IILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;IIIIIILjava/lang/String;IJJJLjava/lang/String;)Lcom/simplemobiletools/calendar/pro/models/Event;", "equals", "other", "", "getCalDAVCalendarId", "getCalDAVEventId", "getEventRepetition", "Lcom/simplemobiletools/calendar/pro/models/EventRepetition;", "getEventStartTS", "getIsAllDay", "getReminders", "", "hashCode", "isOnProperWeek", "startTimes", "Landroidx/collection/LongSparseArray;", "toString", "updateIsPastEvent", "Companion", "calendar_debug"})
public final class Event implements java.io.Serializable {
    private int color;
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable()
    @androidx.room.PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private java.lang.Long id;
    @androidx.room.ColumnInfo(name = "start_ts")
    private int startTS;
    @androidx.room.ColumnInfo(name = "end_ts")
    private int endTS;
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    @androidx.room.ColumnInfo(name = "title")
    private java.lang.String title;
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    @androidx.room.ColumnInfo(name = "location")
    private java.lang.String location;
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    @androidx.room.ColumnInfo(name = "description")
    private java.lang.String description;
    @androidx.room.ColumnInfo(name = "reminder_1_minutes")
    private int reminder1Minutes;
    @androidx.room.ColumnInfo(name = "reminder_2_minutes")
    private int reminder2Minutes;
    @androidx.room.ColumnInfo(name = "reminder_3_minutes")
    private int reminder3Minutes;
    @androidx.room.ColumnInfo(name = "repeat_interval")
    private int repeatInterval;
    @androidx.room.ColumnInfo(name = "repeat_rule")
    private int repeatRule;
    @androidx.room.ColumnInfo(name = "repeat_limit")
    private int repeatLimit;
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    @androidx.room.ColumnInfo(name = "import_id")
    private java.lang.String importId;
    @androidx.room.ColumnInfo(name = "flags")
    private int flags;
    @androidx.room.ColumnInfo(name = "event_type")
    private long eventType;
    @androidx.room.ColumnInfo(name = "parent_id")
    private long parentId;
    @androidx.room.ColumnInfo(name = "last_updated")
    private long lastUpdated;
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    @androidx.room.ColumnInfo(name = "source")
    private java.lang.String source;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -32456795132345616L;
    public static final com.simplemobiletools.calendar.pro.models.Event.Companion Companion = null;

    public final void addIntervalTime(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    com.simplemobiletools.calendar.pro.models.Event original) {
    }

    private final org.joda.time.DateTime addMonthsWithSameDay(org.joda.time.DateTime currStart, com.simplemobiletools.calendar.pro.models.Event original) {
        return null;
    }

    private final org.joda.time.DateTime addXthDayInterval(org.joda.time.DateTime currStart, com.simplemobiletools.calendar.pro.models.Event original, boolean forceLastWeekday) {
        return null;
    }

    public final boolean getIsAllDay() {
        return false;
    }

    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    public final java.util.List<java.lang.Integer> getReminders() {
        return null;
    }

    public final int getEventStartTS() {
        return 0;
    }

    public final long getCalDAVEventId() {
        return 0L;
    }

    public final int getCalDAVCalendarId() {
        return 0;
    }

    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    public final com.simplemobiletools.calendar.pro.models.EventRepetition getEventRepetition() {
        return null;
    }

    public final boolean isOnProperWeek(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    androidx.collection.LongSparseArray<java.lang.Integer> startTimes) {
        return false;
    }

    public final void updateIsPastEvent() {
    }

    public final boolean isPastEvent() {
        return false;
    }

    public final void setPastEvent(boolean isPastEvent) {
    }

    public final int getColor() {
        return 0;
    }

    public final void setColor(int p0) {
    }

    @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable()
    public final java.lang.Long getId() {
        return null;
    }

    public final void setId(@org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable()
    java.lang.Long p0) {
    }

    public final int getStartTS() {
        return 0;
    }

    public final void setStartTS(int p0) {
    }

    public final int getEndTS() {
        return 0;
    }

    public final void setEndTS(int p0) {
    }

    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    public final java.lang.String getTitle() {
        return null;
    }

    public final void setTitle(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    java.lang.String p0) {
    }

    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    public final java.lang.String getLocation() {
        return null;
    }

    public final void setLocation(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    java.lang.String p0) {
    }

    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    public final java.lang.String getDescription() {
        return null;
    }

    public final void setDescription(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    java.lang.String p0) {
    }

    public final int getReminder1Minutes() {
        return 0;
    }

    public final void setReminder1Minutes(int p0) {
    }

    public final int getReminder2Minutes() {
        return 0;
    }

    public final void setReminder2Minutes(int p0) {
    }

    public final int getReminder3Minutes() {
        return 0;
    }

    public final void setReminder3Minutes(int p0) {
    }

    public final int getRepeatInterval() {
        return 0;
    }

    public final void setRepeatInterval(int p0) {
    }

    public final int getRepeatRule() {
        return 0;
    }

    public final void setRepeatRule(int p0) {
    }

    public final int getRepeatLimit() {
        return 0;
    }

    public final void setRepeatLimit(int p0) {
    }

    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    public final java.lang.String getImportId() {
        return null;
    }

    public final void setImportId(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    java.lang.String p0) {
    }

    public final int getFlags() {
        return 0;
    }

    public final void setFlags(int p0) {
    }

    public final long getEventType() {
        return 0L;
    }

    public final void setEventType(long p0) {
    }

    public final long getParentId() {
        return 0L;
    }

    public final void setParentId(long p0) {
    }

    public final long getLastUpdated() {
        return 0L;
    }

    public final void setLastUpdated(long p0) {
    }

    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    public final java.lang.String getSource() {
        return null;
    }

    public final void setSource(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    java.lang.String p0) {
    }

    public Event(@org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable()
    java.lang.Long id, int startTS, int endTS, @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    java.lang.String title, @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    java.lang.String location, @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    java.lang.String description, int reminder1Minutes, int reminder2Minutes, int reminder3Minutes, int repeatInterval, int repeatRule, int repeatLimit, @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    java.lang.String importId, int flags, long eventType, long parentId, long lastUpdated, @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    java.lang.String source) {
        super();
    }

    @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable()
    public final java.lang.Long component1() {
        return null;
    }

    public final int component2() {
        return 0;
    }

    public final int component3() {
        return 0;
    }

    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    public final java.lang.String component4() {
        return null;
    }

    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    public final java.lang.String component5() {
        return null;
    }

    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    public final java.lang.String component6() {
        return null;
    }

    public final int component7() {
        return 0;
    }

    public final int component8() {
        return 0;
    }

    public final int component9() {
        return 0;
    }

    public final int component10() {
        return 0;
    }

    public final int component11() {
        return 0;
    }

    public final int component12() {
        return 0;
    }

    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    public final java.lang.String component13() {
        return null;
    }

    public final int component14() {
        return 0;
    }

    public final long component15() {
        return 0L;
    }

    public final long component16() {
        return 0L;
    }

    public final long component17() {
        return 0L;
    }

    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    public final java.lang.String component18() {
        return null;
    }

    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    public final com.simplemobiletools.calendar.pro.models.Event copy(@org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable()
    java.lang.Long id, int startTS, int endTS, @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    java.lang.String title, @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    java.lang.String location, @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    java.lang.String description, int reminder1Minutes, int reminder2Minutes, int reminder3Minutes, int repeatInterval, int repeatRule, int repeatLimit, @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    java.lang.String importId, int flags, long eventType, long parentId, long lastUpdated, @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    java.lang.String source) {
        return null;
    }

    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    @java.lang.Override()
    public java.lang.String toString() {
        return null;
    }

    @java.lang.Override()
    public int hashCode() {
        return 0;
    }

    @java.lang.Override()
    public boolean equals(@org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable()
    java.lang.Object p0) {
        return false;
    }

    @kotlin.Metadata(mv = {1, 1, 13}, bv = {1, 0, 3}, k = 1, d1 = {"\u0000\u0012\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0010\u0000\n\u0002\b\u0002\n\u0002\u0010\t\n\u0000\b\u0086\u0003\u0018\u00002\u00020\u0001B\u0007\b\u0002\u00a2\u0006\u0002\u0010\u0002R\u000e\u0010\u0003\u001a\u00020\u0004X\u0082T\u00a2\u0006\u0002\n\u0000\u00a8\u0006\u0005"}, d2 = {"Lcom/simplemobiletools/calendar/pro/models/Event$Companion;", "", "()V", "serialVersionUID", "", "calendar_debug"})
    public static final class Companion {

        private Companion() {
            super();
        }
    }
}
```

I fixed kotlin version at current version and rebuild it. But there is not change anything. I search this errors and try their solutions. But didn't worked. And other problem I didn't any change in java file. Android Studio is saying "Files under the "build" folder are generated and should not be edited".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I clone the project
2. update kotlin
3. rename keystore.properties_sample to keystore.properties
4. run it.. and everything works fine.